# ratelimiting with iptables recent gives error

Tags: iptables

Due to a huge number of bots accessing my web server too many times a second, I went into my server and issued the following commands in an attempt to limit connections to a maximum of 25 in 5 seconds. I may need to be more strict, but I'm not because I have one page that is rarely accessed that requests 50 images and that might need 51 connections and I dont want users waiting forever for the remaining 26 pictures.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 5 --hitcount 26 -j DROP
```

The first command works after verifying with iptables -nL but the second command immediately returns this message: "iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information."

As soon as I executed it, I receive the following at the end of it:

```
Call Trace:
<IRQ>  [<ffffffff8112f7ba>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x74a/0x8d0
[<ffffffff81299270>] ? swiotlb_map_page+0x0/0x100
[<ffffffff8116e282>] ? kmem_getpages+0x62/0x170
[<ffffffff8116ee9a>] ? fallback_alloc+0x1ba/0x270
[<ffffffff8116e8ef>] ? cache_grow+0x2cf/0x320
[<ffffffff8116ec19>] ? ____cache_alloc_node+0x99/0x160
[<ffffffff8116fb9b>] ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x11b/0x190
[<ffffffff8144d058>] ? sk_prot_alloc+0x48/0x1c0
[<ffffffff8144e262>] ? sk_clone+0x22/0x2e0
[<ffffffff8149ff16>] ? inet_csk_clone+0x16/0xd0
[<ffffffff814b97d3>] ? tcp_create_openreq_child+0x23/0x470
[<ffffffff814b6f8d>] ? tcp_v4_syn_recv_sock+0x4d/0x310
[<ffffffff814b9576>] ? tcp_check_req+0x226/0x460
[<ffffffff814b69cb>] ? tcp_v4_do_rcv+0x35b/0x490
[<ffffffffa0322557>] ? ipv4_confirm+0x87/0x1d0 [nf_conntrack_ipv4]
[<ffffffff814b825a>] ? tcp_v4_rcv+0x51a/0x900
[<ffffffff81495270>] ? ip_local_deliver_finish+0x0/0x2d0
[<ffffffff8149534d>] ? ip_local_deliver_finish+0xdd/0x2d0
[<ffffffff814955d8>] ? ip_local_deliver+0x98/0xa0
[<ffffffff81494a9d>] ? ip_rcv_finish+0x12d/0x440
[<ffffffff81495025>] ? ip_rcv+0x275/0x350
[<ffffffff8145c3eb>] ? __netif_receive_skb+0x4ab/0x750
[<ffffffff81460058>] ? netif_receive_skb+0x58/0x60
[<ffffffff81460160>] ? napi_skb_finish+0x50/0x70
[<ffffffff814618c9>] ? napi_gro_receive+0x39/0x50
[<ffffffffa024e267>] ? e1000_receive_skb+0x67/0x110 [e1000e]
[<ffffffffa0250e6f>] ? e1000_clean_rx_irq+0x37f/0x580 [e1000e]
[<ffffffffa025397d>] ? e1000e_poll+0x8d/0x2d0 [e1000e]
[<ffffffff814619e3>] ? net_rx_action+0x103/0x2f0
[<ffffffff8107a5f1>] ? __do_softirq+0xc1/0x1e0
[<ffffffff810e6c60>] ? handle_IRQ_event+0x60/0x170
[<ffffffff8107a64f>] ? __do_softirq+0x11f/0x1e0
[<ffffffff8100c30c>] ? call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[<ffffffff8100fa75>] ? do_softirq+0x65/0xa0
[<ffffffff8107a4a5>] ? irq_exit+0x85/0x90
[<ffffffff81532525>] ? do_IRQ+0x75/0xf0
[<ffffffff8100b9d3>] ? ret_from_intr+0x0/0x11
<EOI>
```

The contents before refer to usb devices and other system devices. Can someone tell me how to successfully rate-limit incoming connections without experiencing random errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Executing `dmesg` reveals the cause of the error:

> [78482.351825] xt_recent: hitcount (26) is larger than packets to be remembered (20)

This means that the `recent` module of `iptables` is limited to remembering just 20 packets. In order to solve this issue you can perform *any* of the following:

1. Reduce the value of the `hitcount` parameter in your `iptables` rule from 26 to 20 or less.
   *or*
2. Increase the maximum possible value for the `hitcount` parameter from its default value of 20 by setting the option `ip_pkt_list_tot` of the `xt_recent` kernel module. This can be done by creating an `ip_pkt_list_tot.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` which contains:

   > options xt_recent ip_pkt_list_tot=26

   Once the file is created, reload the `xt_recent` kernel module via `modprobe -r xt_recent && modprobe xt_recent` or reboot the system.

Inspecting `iptables`'s man page leads to the same conclusion:

```
   --hitcount hits
          This option must be used in conjunction with one of --rcheck or --update. When used, this will narrow the match to only happen  when
          the  address  is  in  the list and packets had been received greater than or equal to the given value. This option may be used along
          with --seconds to create an even narrower match requiring a certain number of hits within a specific time frame. The  maximum  value
          for  the  hitcount parameter is given by the "ip_pkt_list_tot" parameter of the xt_recent kernel module. Exceeding this value on the
          command line will cause the rule to be rejected.
```

Note that `xt_recent` is called `ipt_recent` on some systems.

Comment: Just to add a warning that you can't `modprobe -r` when there's one (or more) iptables rule(s) using the `-m recent` module. Check with `iptables-save | grep recent` first. In this case, either temporarily delete those rules, or reboot.

Comment: I use Debian, the folder name is `/etc/modprobe.d` (without the 'e') and the kernel module is called `ipt_recent`.

Comment: @lihume good suggestion. In CentOS the same folder is available. I put there file named ipt.conf with contents `options ipt_recent ip_pkt_list_tot=250 ip_list_tot=2000`